# local variable 'server_name' referenced before assignment in django view

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am creating a Django app which stores servers in a database. The servers come from a list via a third party app. So my app needs to go through the list add any servers that aren't already in the database and delete any that are in the database but aren't in the list. However, when I try to do the deletion part of the requirements I keep getting this `referenced before assignment` error for the part of code which states `Server.objects.filter(server_name in i)`
 Now I am not sure if I can do `server_name in i` the way I have done it but I am just playing around with it. I have got the error when doing the `Server.objects.filter(server_name=i)` (which I know should work). Can anyone help?

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Server
from hive.cloud.pyraxhelpers.pyraxhelpers import list_hostnames
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

def server_home(request):
    return render(request, 'templates/index.html', {})

def server(request):
    server_name = Server.objects.get(server_name)
    for i in list_hostnames():
        print "Going through list"
        if Server.objects.filter(server_name=i).exists():
            print "Server exists so skip"
        else:
            if Server.objects.filter(server_name in i): 
               print "Add the new server"
               server_name = Server.objects.create(server_name=i)
                return HttpResponse("Added")
            else:
                print "Delete"
                return HttpResponse("Deleted")
return HttpResponse("Worked")
```

## Model

```
class Server(models.Model):
    server_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=250)
    renewal_date = models.DateField('expiry date', null=False, default=timezone.now)
    deletion_date = models.DateField('deletion date', null=False, default=timezone.now)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.server_name
```

Comment: From where you get `server_name` argument?

Comment: server_name is from the model and is a field in the database but I don't know how to reference it

Comment: I don't think this line does anything at all since you don't use it later anyway. Just comment it out to see what happens. You also have other problems like two `else` blocks.

Comment: .. and an invalid lookup in the first else block (`sever_name in i`).

Comment: Ignore these problems, the indentation is just stack overflow and I did mention in my post that server_name in i was just me playing around to see what would work. It has no bearing on the error I am questioning. I can't just comment it out because I need it to fulfil the requirement.

Comment: No you don't. That variable defined in the first line, even if it worked, *is not used anywhere*. Remove that line and fix that `in` query.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but it is beside the point. Removing the code doesn't fix the error I have (I have tried), the `in` query doesn't make a difference either, as I said in the original post. And I didn't say it was Stack Overflow's fault, just that the code is only like that in Stack Overflow and not in my actual code, which I know is because of my pasting.

Comment: If you fixed the `in` query you would not have this error.

Comment: It doesn't I've tried it.

Comment: Show what you tried and the exact error you get.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because you're referencing the `server_name` variable before assignment, just like the error says.

The problem is in this line:

> server_name = Server.objects.get(server_name)

What should the second `server_name` variable contain? Python doesn't know.

It looks like you want to add an argument to your call, like `def server(request, server_name)`. Make sure to also change your urls.py.

Comment: server_name is is the model Server, it's a field in the database, how do I reference it then?

Comment: See the edit: I'm unclear of what exactly you're tying to do, but it looks like you want to have an argument `server_name` to your `server(request)` function.

Comment: I want to use the field 'server_name' to check if 'i' in 'list_hostname' is equal to any of the server_names in the database. Adding server_name as an argument won't work because it expects only one argument.

Comment: Please post your model